# What are the scenarios when getFontIndex() API will return negative index?

Tags: java, apache-poi, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using vaadin spreadsheet.  In my program I am reading metadata stored in db like isBold, isItalic, etc and applying these italic , bold etc styles on cell depending on metadata .  After I apply these  styles I have to refresh the cell using spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetStyleFactory().cellStyleUpdated(cell, true);   (Vaadin spreadsheet api). This api sometimes fails throwing ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException which can be found below

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32768
>       at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.getFontAt(StylesTable.java:386) [seqnc-common-jar-1.0.0.jar:]
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle.getFont(XSSFCellStyle.java:557) [seqnc-common-jar-1.0.0.jar:]
>       at com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.XSSFColorConverter.colorStyles(XSSFColorConverter.java:97) [seqnc-common-jar-1.0.0.jar:]
>       at com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetStyleFactory.addCellStyleCSS(SpreadsheetStyleFactory.java:594) [seqnc-common-jar-1.0.0.jar:]
>       at com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetStyleFactory.cellStyleUpdated(SpreadsheetStyleFactory.java:461) [seqnc-common-jar-1.0.0.jar:]

What is happening here is XssfCellStyle is somehow having negative index -32768 which is being used as index in ArrayList.

I Just want to know under what scenarios fontIndex will be set to negative value in XssfCellStyle

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the most recent one, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am using version 3.15 which is the most recent one

Comment: Can you try 3.16 beta 1? If that doesn't help, can you produce a small junit test case showing the problem in conjunction with a very small excel file?

Comment: Tested with 3.16 beta 1. Problem still exists. I will try to comeup with a test case. Thanks!

Comment: Add it to bugzilla and we'll take a look! See http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html#SubmittingPatches - it's almost the same process for bugs as patches

Comment: Issues was because I was creating too many Font objects that I was exceeding Short limit of 32767. Explained in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My code was unnecessarily creating lots of (Around 40,0000 )Font objects.So 40K + fontindexs were needed to store them. But when I saw source of XSSFCellStle.getFontIndex() method integer index was type cast to short

```
 @Override
public short getFontIndex() {
    return (short) getFontId();
}
```

Because I had more than 40K objects, index value was exceeding limit for Short datatype which is 32767. So any index above 32767 was coming as negative short value. I fixed problem by limiting my Font objects to below 32767 range